# Pass value in Schema.pre('update')

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

my update function is

```
 User.update({_id: data._id}, {$set: {password: req.body.newpassword}})
        .then(data => {
          res.json(data)
        })
        .catch(err => {
          res.status(400).json(err);
        });
```

and my `pre` middleware is define as

```
UserSchema.pre('update',function (next) {

 console.log(this.password)  //it shows undefined

});
```

i don't know how to use this so that i can pass my `password` field in `pre` middleware which i further want to hashed

thanx.

Answer (score 1):

You can use node.js `crypto` module for this.

```
var crypto = require('crypto');

var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({ password: 'string' });

UserSchema.pre('update',(next) => {
    this.password = crypto.createHash('md5').update(this.password).digest('hex');
    next();
});

var User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
User.update({_id: data._id}, {$set: {password: req.body.newpassword}})
    .then(data => {
      res.json(data)
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.status(400).json(err);
    });
```

Comment: but it shows `this.password` as` undefined` which you write inside `.update(this.password)`

Comment: You need to define your schema hooks before creating new model. @Rupesh

Comment: will you please explain how to created that schema hooks.

Comment: But when i work with `UserSchema.pre('save')` previous way works perfectly.